# Setting up multiple instances of ejabberd on the same machine

Tags: ejabberd

I am very new to ejabberd. I am trying to setup multiple instances of ejabberd on the same machine(this is for the testing purposes).I feel it is do able but i need to change lot of configuration.It is not same as tomcat(as we can set up multiple instances of the tomcat running on the same machine).Could any one guide me hoe do it in case ejabberd.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that using a different config file (with a different port) and a different node name per ejabberd should do the trick.